# Создание одинаковых html элементов с разными именами

Tags: javascript, html

Есть список с текстовыми полями

```
<input name="multiadd" type="button" value="добавить" class="btn add_many"/>
<ul>
<li>
<textarea name="one"></textarea>
</li>
<li>
<textarea name="two</textarea
</li>
</ul>
```

И кнопка, по нажатию которой весь этот html блок создается еще раз. Вот js, который это делает. Он ориентируется по тегам ul и создает еще 1 копию всего, что находится между ними

```
$(".del").live("click",function(){
    var ulcnt = $(this).parents("ul:first").prevAll(".add_many:first").nextUntil("h2").filter("ul").length;
    if(ulcnt>1){
        var clul = $(this).parents("ul:first").remove();
    }else{
        $(this).parents("ul:first").find(':input:not(:button)').val("");
    }
});
$(".add_many").live("click",function(){
    var clul = $(this).next("ul");
    var nblock = clul.clone();
    nblock.find(':input:not(:button)').val("");
    clul.before(nblock);
    var nul = $(this).next("ul");
    nul.find(".ui-datepicker-trigger").remove();
nul.find(".hasDatepicker").removeClass("hasDatepicker").removeAttr("id");
```

Можете ли вы подсказать, как сделать так, чтобы он еще и делал их с разными именами? Может, просто бы приписывал им число в конце:

```
<textarea name="one"></textarea> - 
<textarea name="one(1)"></textarea> - 
<textarea name="one(2)"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

Клонируйте и сразу меняйте аттрибут на нужный вам, например, так:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".add_many").on("click", function() {
    var line = $('ul li');
    var lineLast = line.last();
    lineLast.clone().find('textarea').attr('name', 'one_' + line.length).end().insertAfter(lineLast);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="multiadd" type="button" value="добавить" class="btn add_many" />
<ul>
  <li>
    <textarea name="one"></textarea>
  </li>
</ul>
```